# Should I flag a duplicate question that both is old and already has an answer?

Tags: discussion, flags, duplicate-questions

I found two questions that are practically the same:

[How to insert an item into an array at a specific index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586182)

[How to push to an array in a particular position?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8754508)

I thought about flagging the more recent one, but it already has an answer since 2012.

**Is there any point in flagging a duplicate question that has had and answer for years?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there most certainly is a point.  You're pointing people that find the duplicate to the canonical, which is going to be a higher quality resource, with better answers.  It also means that new information on the topic only needs to be posted to the canonical, rather than across lots of duplicate questions not closed as duplicates.

Comment: Thank you. That's pretty much what I thought, as well, but I wanted to make sure.